# How to get the output of timeout command without using a shell script

Tags: command-line, stdout, timeout, stderr

I am using a ssh command executor in java which runs the command and gets the output in stderr, stdout and an integer exit value. I am trying run a command with timeout like,

```
    timeout 5s COMMAND
```

Is there a way to get a response in the stderr or the stdout so that I can know whether the command was timed out or not?

Comment: What have you tried? For example, the man page for `timeout` says `If  the  command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit with status 124.` Are you trying to distinguish that from a command that actually does exit with status 124?

Comment: I am pretty much a noob in linux, but all I want is to know whether the command was timed out as an output in stderr or stdout

Comment: @Ipor's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man timeout`:

> ```
>    If  the  command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit
>    with status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of  COMMAND.   If  no
>    signal  is specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The TERM sig‐
>    nal kills any process that does not block or catch that signal.  It may
>    be  necessary  to  use the KILL (9) signal, since this signal cannot be
>    caught, in which case the exit status is 128+9 rather than 124.
> ```

So...
`timeout 5s command || [ $? -eq 124 ] && echo timeouted`

Comment: That worked, thanks. though the ;fi seems unnecessary.

Comment: You may prefer `timeout 5s command ; if [ $? -eq 124 ] ; then echo timed out ; else echo did not time out ; fi` (I think Ipor started with this and forgot to remove the `;fi` :) )

Comment: Thanks, That's much more of a complete answer that I needed. Just a small doubt, this is echoed in stdout right? how do it do it in stderr?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it